# Rest Controller Unit testing Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-restcontroller

while mocking the controller class, i am unable to cover the catch block in my unit testing,

here is the code -
Controller Class -

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseSentence> getText(@RequestBody Text text) throws IOException {

    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(serviceImpl.getText(text), HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

this is my test class

```
  @Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private Service service;

@MockBean
private ServiceImpl serviceImp;
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;



@Test
void getText() throws Exception {
    Text text = new Text();
    text.setText("");

    //given(service.getText(text)).willThrow(new IOException("boom"));
    when(serviceImp.getText(text)).thenThrow(new IOException());

    ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(post("/opennlp/v1/sentence")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(text)));


    response.andDo(print()).
            andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

    Mockito.verify(serviceImp).getText(any());

}
```

while code coverage the catch block is not covered.

Comment: Is `Text` a custom class in your code? Does it have an `equals` method defined?

Comment: no it doent, it is just a model class @Jonasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your problem is the fact that the `Text` instance used in your test method and the `Test` instance present in the actual controller code present when running the test **are two separate instances** and the `Text` class does not have an `equals` method defined. In the test method you're creating an object using the constructor (`new`) and in the controller method a separate instance of the object is passed, created by Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Since no `equals` method is defined, when Mockito compares the objects they do not match and the mocked behavior is not executed.

You can either define the `equals` method in the `Text` class ([remembering about the equals and hashCode methods contract](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts)) or use an [argument matcher](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) when defining the behavior using Mockito, depending on what you'd like to test:

```java
when(serviceImp.getText(any()))
    .thenThrow(new IOException());
```

```java
when(serviceImp.getText(argThat(value => value.getText().isEmpty())))
    .thenThrow(new IOException());
```

```java
String someValue = "custom value";
text.setText(someValue);
when(serviceImp.getText(argThat(value => someValue.equals(value.getText()))))
    .thenThrow(new IOException());
```